# CRC32 not calculating the right checksum?

Tags: python, crc32

I'm trying to calculate the crc32 checksum of a file, but it seems that my code isn't calculating it right.

```
def crc32_checksum(directory):
    file = open(directory, "r").read()
    file_checksum = str(binascii.crc32(file) & 0xffffffff)
    return file_checksum
```

Obviously that will return the decimal checksum (right?), but when I convert it to hex, it doesn't seem to match up (I'm using one of those decimal to hex websites).

I get this as the Python return: `2370036543 (8D43E33F)`
and checksum that the DigitalVolcano HashTool 1.1 I downloaded returns this: `(300654116) 11eb9e24`.

I'm positive that the hashtool is correct as I've done comparing of checksums using it (and they matched).

I'm running Windows.

Comment: @user3371785: please provide the result of hashtool and your code on a short string, e.g. "123456789", assuring that exactly the same string is fed to both.

Comment: @MarkAdler: which is why we close them. I voted to close the other one too. The fabled 'other tool' is present in both, as are the other steps (mask, convert to hex, no details about the file or the tool).

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough detail. I'm using this tool called "DigitalVolcano Hash Tool 1.1".

Comment: @user3371785: can you add a) some sample data and b) the CRC for that data as produced by the DigitalVolcano Hash Tool? Do try and create a file that *reproduces the issue*.

Comment: @MarkAdler: just as a heads-up: this one has been reopened. Not a great question still, but at least a future visitor *may* get some use out of it. Especially if the OP were to edit their question and added the details about OS (Windows) and file contents to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what system you are doing this on, but you may need to open with "rb" instead of "r" to assure that there are no end-of-line translations on the read data.  It is good practice to put that in anyway for portability and to document that you are considering the input to be binary data.

Comment: Although the remark about opening the file in binary mode is almost certainly the cause here, your post is barely more than a comment. The OP should just have included more detail here.

Comment: I'm using Windows. I put the string "i am a user" in a text file and compared and the outcomes were the same. Sorry for not putting much detail in. I will try to fix as much as I can.

Comment: Mark is right. This fixed my issue. Thanks, Mark, and anyone who helped out. (Sorry for being such a crappy user. Will do better next time, I promise. :P)

Comment: @Guthwulf sometimes you can make an educated guess at an answer, based on commonly misunderstood nuances of the programming tools. Such answers are just as educational as answers to more well-specified problems. In this case the question had a code sample that was clearly missing the `b` so it was a good answer.